# set variable function not working

Tags: javascript

```
function eventlisternOnclick(_class, ability, _src, _id){
  var cell_onclick = document.querySelectorAll(_class);
  for(var c = 0; c < cell_onclick.length; c++){
  cell_onclick[c].addEventListener('click', function(){
  //problem here , ability(_src) = fun1(mysrc);
  //error
    ability(_src);
  }, false);
  }
}

function fun1(mysrc){
console.log();
}

eventlisternOnclick("abc", "fun1", "this.src", null);
```

the fun1 is a function and i was trying to set as variable at eventlisterOnclick , and run the function there , but when i type ability(_src); it wont work. how do i set the function in my eventlisternOnclick.

Comment: `"fun1"` ==> `fun1` in `eventlisternOnclick("abc", "fun1", ...`. `fun1` is a function, not string.

Comment: sorry i cant get what you mean , you explain more ?

Comment: When passing function `fun1` to `eventlisternOnclick()`, it should be passed as function reference i.e. function name. It should not be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Check the console for errors..To invoke a function using `()` you must have `function definition` or `function expression`..You are passing `string` as `argument`..Edit: `"this.src"` will not work as expected..`string` will be passed, not `property`

Comment: @darkness what do you intend to do with `this.src`?

Comment: i was trying to set all my class with onclick , and all of them are img , i need to get the src when user clicking it  , so i guess this.src is the better to directly get the src.

Comment: Well, you should have `this.src` in your `fun1` implementation and..`cell_onclick[c].addEventListener('click', ability, false);`

Comment: @darkness I don't think you need to pass the parameter for it since you know which attribute you want to access at onclick event.

Comment: sorry i still dont get what you guys mean ? can you guys make me a sampler ?

Comment: how do i put this.src in my fun1 ? like change mysrc to event and set it like event.src ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the parameter passed is always class then replace

```
document.querySelectorAll(_class);
```

with

```
document.querySelectorAll("." + _class);
```

Also, `fun1` is a string, so if fun1 is available to this scope  then try

```
eventlisternOnclick("abc", fun1, "this.src", null);
```

Complete function could be

```
function eventlisternOnclick(_class, ability, _id){
  var cell_onclick = document.querySelectorAll(_class);
  for(var c = 0; c < cell_onclick.length; c++){
    cell_onclick[c].addEventListener('click', function(){
      ability(this.getAttribute("src"));
  }, false);
  }
}

function fun1(mysrc){
   console.log();
}

eventlisternOnclick("abc", fun1, null);
```

Comment: I think `"this.src"` also need to be `this.src`

Comment: @Tushar, `this.src` as an argument will be `evaluated`, not passed as we expect..My guess is `undefined` will be passed!

Comment: @Tushar he hasn't mentioned what he intends to do with it.

Comment: @Guru, `this.src` in `quotes` is never going to make any sense ;)

Comment: @RayonDabre I agree, I guess OP might want to elaborate on it.

Comment: lolz i have so many mistake , how about the function ? i still cant make it work.

Comment: thank you , i love what you do to the this.src. appreciate ~~ learn well.